# Can't change GameObject color via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas for UI, with an image the same size of the canvas. The `Image` has an `rgba` of `0,0,0,0` , making it invisible (because the `a` is 0). I want to have the image fade into black from a script. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class NavigationC : MonoBehaviour {
    public Image screen;
    float fadeTime = 3f;
    Color colorToFadeTo;

    void StartGame()
    {
        colorToFadeTo = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 255f);
        screen.CrossFadeColor(colorToFadeTo, fadeTime, true, true);
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't do anything when executed. But when I change the image's `a` value manually in unity so that the image becomes visible, I can see the script changing the image's color. So the script does work, it just isn't visible because the `a` value is not being changed by the script.
So how can I make the image fade from invisible to black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, **255f**);`

The `Color` constructor parameter takes values from `0f` to `1f` but you are passing `0f` to `255f` range value to it.

That should be:

```
colorToFadeTo = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
```

*If you want to use the `0` to `255` range then you must divide it by `255`.*

```
colorToFadeTo = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 255f/255f);
```

---

Also, there is [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-ctor.html) which can take values between `0` and `255`. You can use that then covert it back to color.

```
Color32 color32 = new Color32(0f, 0f, 0f, 255f));
Color color = color32;
```

Comment: Then why does 255f work **perfectly** when I give the image a color to start with?

Comment: And I tried 1f before going to 255f, 1f didn't work either.

Comment: And now I can't even get 255f or any other value to work, even when I give the picture a color to start with; it just jumps to black or doesn't change at all.

Comment: Read the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) if you are still in doubt. It clearly says that it expects range from `0f` to `1f`. Look at all the static variables in that link. They use `0` to `1`. None of them uses `255` or anything above `1`. If it is changing so fast, pass `false` to the `ignoreTimeScale` parameter. `screen.CrossFadeColor(colorToFadeTo, fadeTime, false, true);`

Comment: Like I said... I did try `1f`. Just saying that unity doesn't behave differently when I alternate between `1f` and `255f`. They both work or don't work, though obviously not how I want them to. In the end I fixed the issue by putting the image's `a` to 1 out of 255. I don't know why that works, but starting with 0 doesn't, but it works nonetheless. I don't doubt your answer and I know what you say is the full truth, just saying that it is not the one thing causing this issue.

Comment: My image `a` default is set to `1` (out of 255) instead of `0`, and I use `255f` instead of `1f`. **I know** that this is not supposed to work, and I know that you are right about everything you said, yet if I change EITHER of these values, it breaks.

Comment: It's just that your first three comment is talking about 255. As for your last comment, it may be working for you now but this is an *undefined* behavior. It may not work on other platforms. You may get another behavior anytime after updating Unity. I feel like this question is totally missing a lot of information. Can you create a new question and include the default values which you never mentioned in your question. Show animated image of what is currently happening. I will take a look at it. Just make sure you don't include 255 in it. That's up to you. I don't think this problem is solved.

Comment: I will make a new question with video soon because I agree that what I did is just a workaround, but I did state the values... "The image has an rgba of 0,0,0,0 , making it invisible (because the a is 0)."

Comment: Forgot to mention, I did change `CrossFadeColor` to `CrossFadeAlpha`, it works but with the same issues...

Comment: Ok, I will wait for your new question. Just want to see the current behavior.